# Can't install php7.3-gd on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, php

I have php7.3 installed but I can't install the gd module.

I have tried running the following commands:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.3-gd
```

I get the following error:

E: Unable to locate package php7.3-gd

Answer (score 1):

Php7.3-gd is outdated and probably removed from default linux repositories. You should install the version 7.4. Try this command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install php7.4-gd
```